# instafeed.js to get list of media liked by a specific user

Tags: javascript, instagram, instafeedjs

i want to collect all the images liked by a specific user.
I have the access token.
can't find how to achieve this through instafeed.js plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instagram API endpoint for getting a list of media liked a user is only for the currently authenticated user, not any specific user.

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

[image]

If that's what you want, then **instafeed.js** currently does not support this end point :(

The good news is that [this pull request](https://github.com/nixonnixon/instafeed.js/commit/b5d915a7f8ae49d7f3160297884669db7a2fa9a6) on the [instafeed.js repository](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js) on github implements the end point.

[image]

[The owner](https://github.com/stevenschobert) of instafeed.js has not merged it into the main repository / source code, but if you want this functionality, you can download this commit, or merge the highlighted code into your local copy of the instafeed.js javascript file and try it out.

```
    case "liked":
      if (typeof this.options.accessToken !== 'string') {
        throw new Error("No access token. Use the 'accessToken' option.");
      }
      endpoint = "/users/self/media/liked";
      break;
```